# Memoir and geometry

Tags: margins, memoir, geometry

I am using [geometry](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry) with [memoir](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/).

I use it to change the margins of my document temporarily, e.g.:

```
....
\savegeometry{the_original_geometry}
\newgeometry{top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm,headsep=0cm}
....
\loadgeometry{the_original_geometry}
....
```

I think memoir supplies its own set of commands for adjusting margins. I looked into the documentation but I couldn't find a command that was as intuitive as those above, and that allows me to switch quickly between two types of layouts

Is there a way to do this using `memoir`'s commands and avoid using the `geometry` package ?

Also, a related question: How do I get geometry or memoir to print the current values of `top`, `bottom` and `headsep`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to check all the page parameters is to use the layouts package (written by Peter Wilson the same author of memoir) and used by the class to illustrate them in the manual.

There is no notion of top, bottom, left or right as defined by geometry (they are just convenience lengths for calculations and for author inputs). Similarly memoir offers some lengths that are not available clearly in geometry, such as `\trimtop` etc.

`top` is equivalent to `\uppermargin` in memoir, `\headsep` is a LaTeX length and available in both.

The page layout parameters can all be changed using the LaTeX `\setlength` command.
For example, to set the `headsep=0pt`, put this into the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
\makeatother
```

To view any dimension in a document just use the `\showthe` or `\the` macros. For example
to view the `headsep` values use  `\showthe\headsep` or simply `\the\headsep` to print it.
See [Page geometry discrepancies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54694/page-geometry-discrepancies) for a short macro to print all the lengths.