# memoir class: equivalent setting to yield 6 x 9 US trade book

Tags: memoir

I'm using the [`memoir` document class](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir) to compose a book. The book will be printed as a hard-cover 6" x 9" (Inch) US trade book. The `memoir` user guide has a chapter about page layout and provides settings for many different types of book sizes, however, I don't see any size that matches 6" x 9".

How can I configure `memoir`, to yield 6" x 9" page size?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`layouts` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/layouts), as discussed in [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54829/134641), to list and depict `memoir` page sizes, beyond the standard ones on offer.

You will have to manually tune and adjust the layout, to properly typeset a 6" x 9" document, suitable for publication in (publisher-dependent) US Trade Book format.

Guidelines for this process can be found within Section 4, of the [`layouts` User Manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/layouts/layman.pdf), entitled "The memoir class page layout".

Here is some sample code, adapted from there, to help you get started:

```
\begin{figure}
    \currentstock

    \trystockheight{10in}
    \trystockwidth{7in}
    \trytrimtop{1in}
    \trytrimedge{1in}

    \trypaperheight{9in}
    \trypaperwidth{6in}
    
    \tryspinemargin{0.75in}
    \tryuppermargin{1.0in}
    \tryheadheight{12pt}
    \tryheadsep{24pt}
    \trytextwidth{5in}
    \trytextheight{7in}
    \tryfootskip{24pt}
    \setfootbox{50pt}{50pt}
    \trymarginparsep{17pt}
    \trymarginparwidth{62pt}
    \trymarginparpush{12pt}
    \setlabelfont{\small}
    \stockdesign
    
    \caption{An experimental US Trade Book \file{memoir} class page layout}\label{fig:pmemudf}
\end{figure}
```

You can, however, directly use [`geometry`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) with `memoir`. So you could just try adding something like the below to your preamble:

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in, bindingoffset=0.75in]{geometry}
```

As mentioned in the previously-linked answer, however, it might be better to do this directly with `memoir` commands, as discussed above.

Comment: @Lambert You're most welcome! If you feel that this helped you, please [up-vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/359826) my Answer. If this solved your problem, please [mark this Answer correct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/359826).

I also suggest you read [this](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3262/376016) as well as [these guidelines](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/134641), to improve your experience on TeX.SE.