# how to get the page layout in mm?

Tags: memoir, book-design

I try to understand the actual page layout - but like to have it in mm units. I use `layouts` but get the sizes in pt. There is a command `\printinunitsof{mm}` but I do not understand how to use it. In my example code, it does not have an effect. Where does it belong?

```
\documentclass[msmallroyalvopaper
    ]{memoir}

\usepackage{layouts}

\begin{document}

\printinunitsof{mm}
\begin{figure}
    \currentpage
    \oddpagelayouttrue
    \pagedesign
    \caption{Odd page layout for this document} \label{fig:ptrs}
\end{figure}

\include{intro}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The unit `pt` is hardcoded in the definition of `\pagedesign`.

Comment: @egreg any reason as to why that is so?

Comment: You must use also commands like  `\prntlen{\headsep}` to have these lengths printed in mm, or use [this macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8337/11604) but obviously as an add, without modifying the `\pagedesign` output.

Comment: @naphaneal The author decided to round the shown lengths to an integer number of points. Respecting the setting of `\printinunitsof` would require extensive rewriting.

Comment: Using the `pgf` package, I tried with `paperwidth \prntlen{\the\paperwidth}\\` in the definition from <https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54694/page-geometry-discrepancies> but get completely unreasonable output `paperwidth .86299pt0.35146mm` for a 444pt. What am I not understanding?

Comment: `\prntlen{\paperwidth}`,  not `\prntlen{\the\paperwidth}` and with `\printinunitsof{mm}` before

Comment: @naphaneal In typography the basic length unit is the pt. I assumed that anyone working/checking a typographic design would be using pts.

Comment: @PeterWilson there are a number of definitions for `pt`. hence my question. there's `French`, `American`, `Metric` and the `DTP` definition. which one is hardcoded in LaTeX?